# How can I get the jsessionid from a response using react js?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cookies, request, jsessionid

**Context**

- Spring Boot
- React Js

**Issue**

I want to make a login request from **react** to get the `jsessionid`. I am getting a weird response from **Spring Boot**. In the response i don't find any cookies. In postman i can just give the username and password in the url as parameters and in the response I am getting a response with the cookie `jsessionid` and for more requests I can just use it. But in **react** I am getting a weird response and I don't know how to get the cookie.

Here is the code that sends the request from **React JS** to **Spring Boot**:

```
const { username, password } = this.state;
    const student = { username, password };
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/login", {
      method: "POST",
      body: new URLSearchParams(student)
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        const jsessionid = document.cookie;
        console.log("id", jsessionid);
        //Here I am trying to get the jsessionid
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fof12.png) is the response that I am getting and that I printed out in the console

And here is my **Spring Securtiy Configuration Class**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable().cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }



}
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cgAN.png) I tried with curl and as you can see I am getting the cookie `jsessionid` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access your `jsessionid` from response.header

for example

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080/login", {
  method: "POST",
  body: new URLSearchParams(student)
  credentials: 'include', 
  headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  } 
  })
  .then(res=>console.log(res.headers.get('set-cookie'));)

  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! So if I try to parse it into json im getting this error ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0```

Comment: I've updated the answer, please have a look. I can't check the code so let me know whats the result.

Comment: try `credentials: 'same-origin'`

Comment: It's working but without the credentials: 'include' but the problem now is that I always have to pass the data as url search parameters. I want to have it in the body.

Comment: instead of `body: new URLSearchParams(student)` using `body: JSON.stringify(this.state.student)` and   your state shoul be like this: `user:{
        username: 'user1',
        password: '123'
        
      }`

Comment: As I said it also works with out ```credentials: 'include'``` so it did not help me but thanks for answering! :D

Comment: Also I want to send the data in the body but spring security forces me to put the credentials in the url as params. How can I configure Spring so that I can put the credentials in the body instead in the url as parameter?

Comment: You can't simply ask someone to create a piece of code for you. Try doing by yourself, and ask the community to improve or correct.

Comment: Hi did you manage it? How do you send the cookie back to spring boot? @user11524064